# How to access vuex state from vueRouter in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-router

Hi I'm trying  access to vuex state from VueRouter instance, but i can't get the state properly.

Attempting to access the `$store` property of `router.app` says it is null

Here my vueRouter code:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const isLoggedIn = router.app.$store.getters["user/isLogedIn"];
    if (to.name !== "Login" && !isLoggedIn) {
        next({ name: "Login" });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

In vuex store:

```
export const getters = {
  isLoggedIn(state) {
    if (state && state.user) {
      console.log("state.user", state.user);
    }
    return state.user !== null && state.user !== {};
  },
};
```

Here is my vueRouter object:

VueRouter Object:
[image]

And here is the error that i have:

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

other way is to import your store in router file like

```
import storeA from './pathToStore'
```

and use in store like

```
storeA.getters.isLoggedIn
```

Comment: Also i'm tired this `window.$nuxt.$store.getters["user/isLogedIn"]` but says that windows is not Defined.

Comment: by seeing the error message that you have posted It says `can't read $store of null` there must be some place  you are using `<someObject>.$store` debug properly and see from which line it is coming error.